# how to represent product_id and product attribute data in redis

Tags: redis

I have data with multiple Products, Product_id: 1  and Product_attributes: Vitamin_A -> 200, Vitamin_D -> 400 Product_id: 2  and Product_attributes: Vitamin_A -> 200, Vitamin_D -> 400 ....
What is the best way to store this in Redis store ? I was thinking about HMSET but I don't know whether it will be possible to access each individual attribute (Vitamin_A for example) through that ?

Answer (score 1):

A hash in Redis is a perfect use case for this. You can grab the individual field inside the hash doing `HGET product_id:1 Vitamin_A` or get all of the attributes using `HGETALL product_id:1`. Take a look [at the hash commands](https://redis.io/commands#hash) for more info.

Comment: What if we have multiple products 1,2,3, ... 100? Can't I store it on one hash ?

Comment: You could store them in their own hash. Redis doesn't support nested hashes, so you wouldn't be able to access the individual product fields if you used one hash for everything. That also doesn't scale that well (if you are concerned about that) since one key cannot be sharded across multiple Redis instances.

Comment: Then what is the best solution for scaling it well and storing such data?

Comment: Using multiple hashes scales better than using one hash. You can also have a Redis set that contains the IDs for every product, which would allow you to know how many products exist.